# Approximation $\ln \frac{(h+f)!}{(h-g)!}$ using Stirling’s when $f+g=o(h)$

Tags: approximation, factorial

Stirling’s approximation can be extended to a very well known inequality -

$$\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \leq n! \leq e\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

How can we use this to prove,

$$\ln \frac{(h+f)!}{(h-g)!} = (f+g)\ln h \pm O\left(\frac{(f+g)^2}{h}\right) $$

when $f+g=o(h)$

#### My Attempt

$$
\begin{align}
\ln \frac{(h+f)!}{(h-g)!} &= \ln \frac{\left(h+f\right)^{h+f+1/2}}{\left(h-g\right)^{h-g+1/2}} + \ln \frac{e^{h-g}}{e^{h+f}}\\ &= (h+f+1/2)\ln(h+f) - (h-g+1/2)\ln(h-g) - (f+g)
\end{align}
$$

At this point I can use property of logarithms $\ln(h+f)=\ln h+\ln(1+f/h)$ and $\ln(h-g)=\ln h+\ln(1-g/h)$ to extract $\ln h$ terms. But that would leave a lot of other terms with itself which I'm not able to collate.

How should I move ahead from hear? If this is not the right approach then I hope to be pointed towards right direction.

Comment: I never saw the very well known inequality :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should not have presumed too much. But the inequality is there on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), and quite straight forward to prove as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue, you can use the Taylor expansion of logarithm, just the beginning:
$$ \ln(1+x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$$
That gives you
$$ (h+f+1/2)\ln(1+f/h) = f + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{f^2}{h}\right) $$
and $$-(h-g+1/2)\ln(1+g/h) = g + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{g^2}{h}\right) $$

However, note that Stirling's approxiamtion won't give you the exact equality as you're writing it. What you can get from them is 
$$ \ln (n!) = (n+1/2)\ln n - n + \xi(n)$$
where $\xi(n) \in [\ln\sqrt{2\pi},1]$. This last term is negligible compared to the leading term, but it doesn't vanish. In the end, the best you can get this with this method is
$$ \ln\frac{(h+f)!}{(h-g)!} = (f+g)\ln h  + \xi + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{f^2}{h},\frac{g^2}{h}\right)  $$
where $\xi = \xi(h+f)-\xi(h-g)$, $|\xi| \le 1-\ln\sqrt{2\pi}$